GCP Application Default Credentials conflict
I have two projects running locally which both use Application Default Credentials. One is in Spring Boot and one is in NodeJS. They use different projects on my same GCP account.
The NodeJS one was working fine and using Google's auth library to authenticate and then use the Google Sheets API.
I then started the Spring Boot one which points to a GCP SQL server. To get this working, I had to change the project that the gcloud CLI was referring to, and then run gcloud auth application-default login. This then worked and I was able to access everything needed for this app.
When trying to move back to the NodeJS project I was unable to authenticate, which I expected. However, when I pointed the gcloud CLI back to this project and ran gcloud auth application-default login again, I was still unable to authenticate. I also expected the Spring Boot app to fail again, but it still worked.
There are two interesting lines in the console when I start up the Spring Boot app:
c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [{Scopes for Spring Boot App}]
c.g.c.s.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is {MYNODEJSAPP}

Why have the default credentials retained the wrong scope despite changing to the correct project ID?
Also, is there a better way to manage two sets of ADCs locally than needing to keep switching the project in the CLI?

Did you set your project to use somewhere?

What do you mean? @guillaumeblaquiere

I don't understand your issue. the gcloud auth app default login is for authenticating you, as an account. From there, your permission are used  to access different APIs. You can set a default quota project to change the default project, but you can also set this project value in your code directly. The runtime of an application that use the ADC file do not modify it, it read only it to generate Access Token (from the refresh token) contained in the ADC file; no more, no project relationship. Or you missed to share important information.

@guillaumeblaquiere Basically when I run my NodeJS project locally the default credential doesn't have authorisation to access the Sheets API when it definitely did before I started using the other project

How do you access the sheetAPI then? Do you change the scope?

Application Default Credentials (ADC) is a method of finding credentials. The Google Cloud SDK clients will using ADC to find a credential to use. By using the command gcloud auth application-default login, you are setting up a credential that ADC will find. If you want to use different credentials in each of your applications, then you must specify a credential to use. For development, I recommend using a service account per application and switching the service account using the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=SERVICE-ACCOUNT-FILE before starting each application.

See this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials

Since you are developing an application that will require specifying OAuth scopes for the Sheets API, you will need to modify your application to include those scopes. I recommend that you stop using ADC entirely otherwise you will have a working application using default user credentials now that will later fail once you deploy in the cloud. The credentials that you are using in your question (user credentials) will not exist in the cloud. In the cloud, you should use credentials from the metadata service.

@guillaumeblaquiere I have no idea. I'm so confused. Seems I don't really know what the default credential is supposed to achieve

@JohnHanley I have already deployed this Node App to the cloud and it works as expected using the service account, and locally it ran using the ADC, that's why I'm so confused that it has now stopped working locally

"switching the service account using the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=SERVICE-ACCOUNT-FILE", ...but the application_default_credentials.json is overwritten each time you run gcloud auth app-def... and I can't see any flag to write the file to a different path, so how would I maintain the two different files?

The service account key file is not a good solution (and I recommend to avoid it). In fact, I would like to know what you want to achieve. Do you want to start the 2 services with the same identity (yours) or 2 different identities? If it's 2, how do you proceed today? Do you have service account key file? Do you use impersonation? What's your exact  context?

@guillaumeblaquiere They are both "me" but they are two different service accounts on two different projects. I own both on the same GCP account

Agreed, things might work for you, but do you understand why? I recommend reading the SDK documentation for the client that you are using. You are trying to declare credentials with the developer tools. My comment is about how to specify credentials in your code. Tip: Do not switch service accounts using the CLI, use the environment variable as I previously mentioned. Note: you are using user credentials via cloud auth login. That is not recommended. Always use a service account (desktop) or the metadata service (in the cloud) when possible. Google search for more details.

I strongly recommend studying the documentation on credentials. Google has made credentials very easy to use so that users can get started easily. But do not use those methods once you understand how to set things up. Before you deploy, make sure you have a solid foundation.

"use the environment variable as I previously mentioned" Yes and I already asked how to manage two json files and you didn't answer. However, you have helped me remember that I had previously signed in with --impersonate-service-account when it was working and when it "broke" I wasn't using this. Literally that was the only thing missing. I don't know why you couldn't have just said that instead of "don't do this", "don't do that", "read the docs", and other obtuse comments

I agree with Chris here... the google docs and some comments here simply imply one should store long lived service account key json files on you personal laptop which is a bit stupid. Impersonation should be the solution which can/should be backed by an SSO/MFA flow
